# Include double quotes in JSON string built from multiple columns

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have an AWS glue spark script, which processes account data.
A new column is required, containing a JSON array of payment data.
The JSON array is built from a number of JSON strings grouped by account_id and batch_date.
Each JSON string will include an payment_amount, payment_date and a payment_type
The output of the job is a csv file, in which the JSON array should be included as a column for processing downstream.

I have almost everything working as I need, except that I'm struggling to include double quotes around names / values within the string items JSON strings.

**How it works currently**

Add a payment_info column to df, concatenating the required column names and values, along with characters to build JSON string.

```
payments_df = payments_df.withColumn('payment_info',fun.concat(fun.lit('{'),fun.lit('"'),fun.lit('payment_date'),fun.lit('"'),fun.lit(':'),fun.col('payment_date'),fun.lit(',payment_amount'),fun.lit(':'),fun.col('payment_amount'),fun.lit(',payment_type'),fun.lit(':'),fun.col('payment_type'),fun.lit('}')))
```

Subsequent steps (these are working as expected):

Group items in the payments_df, rolling the payment_info up to account_id & batch_date level

```
payments_df= payments_df.groupBy("account_id","batch_date").agg(fun.collect_list("payment_info").alias("packaged_payments_json_array"))
```

Convert the array type column packaged_payments_json_array to a string so that it can be easily dealt with

```
payments_df= payments_df.withColumn("packaged_payments_json_array",concat_ws(",",col("packaged_payments_json_array")))
```

Add leading and trailing square bracket to packaged_payments_json_array column

```
payments_df= payments_df.withColumn("packaged_payments_json_array",fun.concat(fun.lit('['),col("packaged_payments_json_array"),fun.lit(']')))
```

Create a temp view so that the packaged_payments_json_array column can be added to other dataframes

```
payments_df.createOrReplaceTempView("payments_somethingsomething_vw")
```

**Output**
The csv files output from the job, contains a 'packaged_payments_json_array' column which looks like this

```
"[{\"payment_date\":2022-05-31,payment_amount:0.00,payment_type:},{\"payment_date\":2022-05-31,payment_amount:28.83,payment_type:INTEREST ON PURCHASE(S)},{\"payment_date\":2022-05-31,payment_amount:0.60,payment_type:INTEREST ON PURCHASE(S)},{\"payment_date\":2022-05-31,payment_amount:29.43,payment_type:FINANCE CHARGE MEMO}]"
```

***Problem***
As you can see in the above example, the double quotes around payment_date are preceded by a backslash, I want only double quotes around each name & value.

***What I have tried***

- Apostrophes wrapping double quotes.
- Three pairs of double quotes around the quotes I want returned.
- preceding the double quotes with a backslash to escape the double quotes (I think that's the correct term)
- Each of the above, within the spark lit() function
- Each of the above, where double quotes are concatenated separately and as part of another string within the concat function.

I think I may be missing something fundamental, but I've trawled many posts, documentation and experimented with everything I can think of, but to no avail.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a hotfix, you can find every \" and replace it with " only.

Comment: Valid JSON requires that strings be double-quoted, so if that string is itself with double-quotes then they must be escaped with backslashes.  So `payment_date` looks to be correctly quoted, whereas `payment_amount` and `payment_type` are not.  Moreover, in the first object in the array `payment_type` has no value and none of the string values are quoted in any of the objects.  Rather than trying to fix your hand-rolled JSON tool I'd suggest re-framing the question as something like "How can I create an array of JSON objects from these dataframe columns?".

Comment: Thanks, in the end I moved away from csv output entirely, and instead output json, bypassing the issue.